# How to tell a shell command is program or function?

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to know whether the *commands* that we call in the shell are  *functions* or *programs*.

Comment: What distinction are you making between "small program" and "function"?

Comment: You can enter commands into a shell program that let you program the shell to function and take command utilizing functions that the shell was programmed with to command other programs from the shell functions.

Answer (score 16):

It depends.

Commands can fall into multiple categories: builtins, aliases,
functions, executables (scripts and binaries in the search path).

On the command line, these occupy a single, flat namespace which
makes overriding possible. There are numerous ways of telling
kinds of programs apart:

```
$ f () { :; }
$ alias a=cat
$ which f
f ()
{ 
    :
}
```

We know that `f` is a function.

```
$ which a
alias a='cat'
        /usr/bin/cat
```

We know that `a` is an alias.

```
$ which yes
/usr/bin/yes
```

We know that `yes` is a program.

```
$ builtin echo ; echo $?

0
```

The shell has an `echo` builtin …

```
$ builtin cat ; echo $?
bash: builtin: cat: not a shell builtin
1
```

… but none for `cat`. If there is a builtin or an alias
but you insist on calling the program instead, prefix the
command with a backslash:

```
$ builtin true | printf "%d\n" $?
0
$ alias true=false
$ true ; printf "%d\n" $?
1
$ \true ; printf "%d\n" $?
0
```

Comment: Also, a command that's a program in one implementation of *nix might well become a shell builtin (= function) in another.

Comment: @jamesqf, yeah, shell's have standard tools built in, but builtin commands are not the same as functions. Run e.g. `sh -c 'type true; f() { echo x; }; type f'`

Comment: Note that in general, `type` is preferable to `which` for almost all purposes.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/135943

Comment: @ilkkachu: That depends on your definition of "the same as".  Of course they are implemented differently, but to the ordinary user typing a command, they are functionally the same.

Comment: @jamesqf, even if your ordinary user doesn't (know how to) use functions, claiming they're the same as builtins is just confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of a `function` is returning single values, and does not output anything. Shell functions in particular may very well and could have an output or other side effects, since the return value of functions is so limited.

A `command` is an instruction given by a user to tell a computer to do something, for example, executing a single program or a group of linked programs.

A `program` is a sequence of instructions (i.e. commands) that are given to a computer and understandable by the computer's central processing unit (CPU). these instructions indicates which operations the computer should perform on a set of data.

Having said that, `functions` are logical subset of the program. Calling one is entirely within your process. The `command` is a program (or a shell built-in) can be executed from the command shell. The command implements functions which perform a task. The opposite is not correct.

Comment: "a function returns a single value, and does not output anything" -- well, yeah, in the mathematical sense maybe. But in imperative programming languages, it's really common for "function" to mean just a subroutine, one that could do anything. And shell functions in particular may very well have output or other side effects, since the return value of functions is so limited.

Comment: @ilkkachu. Thank you. I have updated the answer. Please feel free to revise ;-)

Comment: I think these definitions are from a programming-language context, not a shell context.  Yes, I know the shell language *is* a programming language, but its idea of a "function" is quite different to the mathematical or computer-science definition - in shell, all commands (whether builtins, functions, aliases, programs or scripts) act alike, and are simply different kinds of implementation.

Comment: ...*mostly* alike; builtins can change the state of the shell itself, whereas external programs can't call `chdir()` or `setenv()` in the shell that is, to them, a distinct parent process.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know whether the commands that we call in the shell are functions or programs?

Yes.

Specifically, when you type in some text and press `enter`, the shell must determine whether it's:

1. an `alias`,
2. a function,
3. a built-in command,
4. an executable file.